# s:convertDateTime not working in h:selectManyCheckbox

Tags: jsf, jboss, seam

I'm using JSF 1.2 with Seam and am trying to get a date formatted as dd/MM/yyyy within an h:selectManyCheckbox. The functionality of the h:selectManyCheckbox works fine in itself - it's just that it doesn't display the date correctly.

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox id="paymentDates" value="#{entity.selectedPaymentDates}" layout="pageDirection" styleClass="radio">
    <s:convertDateTime type="date" dateStyle="short" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
    <s:selectItems value="#{entity.calculatedPaymentDates}" var="entity" label="#{entity}" hideNoSelection="true" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Any ideas greatfully appreciated!

AJ

Answer (score 0):

How is the date displayed?
you're using dateStyle with pattern.  Use one or the other, not both.  'short" will format the date as:

> 5/14/07 12:55:42 PM

Though I think you'd have to use style="both" to get the time portion.

If you want to use a specific pattern try:

```
<s:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
```

or maybe:

```
<s:convertDateTime type="both" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
```

Comment: I tried these, but it didn't work. The date is currently being displayed as 'Thu Dec 20 00:00:00 GMT 2012'

Comment: how about: `<h:selectManyCheckbox id="paymentDates" value="#{entity.selectedPaymentDates}" layout="pageDirection" styleClass="radio">
    <s:convertDateTime type="both" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
    <s:selectItems value="#{entity.calculatedPaymentDates}" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox> `